# What is the difference between Android Material Design UI and Android UI without material design?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I am working on an android application. I am going to design User Interface and i have to use material design in it. I want to know what is the difference between Android Material Design UI and Android UI without material design ?
How should i use material design in my application.

Comment: [Material for you](https://material.io/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have to provide UI which fits the suggestions and rules from https://material.io/guidelines/

That resource does describe, for example, minimum sizes for UI elements, padding, margin, etc.

For the newest SDK versions of android most of these rules are already applied into default ui elements in Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Material design is a comprehensive guide for visual, motion, and interaction design across platforms and devices. See [The documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/material/index.html)

Material Design can be used in API Level 21 (Android 5.0) and newer or via the v7 appcompat library, which is used on virtually all Android devices.
In Material Design lot of new things were introduced like Material Theme, new widgets, custom shadows, vector drawables and custom animations

For more information [Go here](https://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/)

There are lot of UI libraries available which you can use in your application.[Find out here](https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui)